# Doctrine2 DQL TRIM with parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to execute an update query in DQL to a mysql database with Doctrine2. Here is my code:

```
        $updateFiles = $entityManager
                ->createQuery("UPDATE Attachment a "
                . "SET a.filename=CONCAT(:dst, TRIM(LEADING :src FROM a.filename)) "
                . "WHERE a.owner=:ownerId AND a.filename LIKE :srcLike");
        $updateFiles->setParameter("dst", $dstFile);
        $updateFiles->setParameter("src", $srcFile);
        $updateFiles->setParameter("ownerId", $this->owner->getId());
        $updateFiles->setParameter("srcLike", $srcFile.'/%');
        $updateFiles->execute();
```

When I execute this code, I get the following syntax error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 77: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ':src'
```

I try to execute the query without TRIM and CONCAT and it works. If I replace :src by 'somerandomtext' there is no error. The syntax of TRIM is [correct](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)! For some reason, the parameter :src is not replaced.

Is this a bug or did I miss something ?

Comment: have you tried renaming src with something else?

Comment: Yes, it does not work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the code the implementation of the TRIM function in DQL, and it seems that I cannot use a parameter for the characters 'trchar'.

```
TRIM([LEADING | TRAILING | BOTH] [‘trchar’ FROM] str)
```

So I will just concat the string with the query :

```
$updateFiles = $entityManager
            ->createQuery("UPDATE Attachment a "
            . "SET a.filename=CONCAT(:dst, TRIM(LEADING $srcFile FROM a.filename)) "
            . "WHERE a.owner=:ownerId AND a.filename LIKE :srcLike");
```